# Activate Python virtual env with QProcess?

Tags: python, qt, environment-variables

Been pulling my hair on this one for a while now and I could use help.

Here is what I have so far:

```
QString l_command = QString("%1").arg(l_filePython);
QString l_activate = QString("%1/Scripts/activate").arg(l_pathPython);

QStringList l_paths;
l_paths << l_pathPython;
l_paths << QString("%1/Scripts").arg(l_pathPython);
l_paths << QString("%1/Library/bin").arg(l_pathPython);
l_paths << QString("%1/Lib").arg(l_pathPython);

QProcessEnvironment l_env = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment();
l_env.insert("Path", QString("%1;%2").arg(l_paths.join(";")).arg(QString(qgetenv("Path"))));

m_QtProcess->setProgram(l_activate + ";" + l_command);
m_QtProcess->setArguments(l_arguments);
m_QtProcess->setProcessEnvironment(l_env);
m_QtProcess->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedErrorChannel);
m_QtProcess->start(QProcess::ReadWrite);
m_QtProcess->waitForStarted();
```

It just hang there... My guess is that the environment is been activated but the second part of the command never gets through. How to execute 2 consecutives command with QProcess?

EDIT: the normal way (without activating the environment):
m_QtProcess->setProgram(l_command);
ptyhon/path/python.exe script/path/myscript.py arg1 arg2 arg3...

Comment: The `QProcess::start` overload you're using expects the program parameter to specify a single executable file.  Can you [edit] your question to show how you would normally run the required command(s) in a console?

Answer (score 0):

`;` does not work on windows as command separator, you probably meant `&&`, still it will not work because `QProcess` runs single executable not a shell script, you can try

```
m_QtProcess->setProgram("cmd.exe");
m_QtProcess->setArguments({"/c", l_activate, "&&", l_command});
```

But I wont guarantee it will work.

I dont think envoronment has anything to do with it, as it's activate's job to setup the environment.